# ESLint for Visual Studio 2017 won't display any errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, eslint

On Visual Studio 15.9.22 I'm unable to get any ESlint errors to appear in my Typescript project.

I don't believe I need to install any extra extension with this version of Visual Studio - just enable ESLint here:

[image]

I have an .eslintrc file in the directory indicated in that screenshot.

Resetting the global .eslintrc doesn't make any noticeable change - I still see not errors.

Any idea what else I could check for?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Lint all files included in project, even closed files" option in your screenshot. It is checked in my settings and I receive ESLint errors.

If that still doesn't work, I would check the .eslintrc file for configuration issues. This link will help in that regard: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/#using-configuration-files

Comment: The "lint all files" option doesn't make any difference. Is there a way I can validate a .eslintrc file automatically? There doesn't appear to be any issue with it as far I can tell. This feels like a more core issue with VS17

Comment: @codedude, Maybe more going on here. Eslint has a dependency on certain node.js versions. I think your version of vs uses eslint v.4, so you may need to Google that version's dependencies and compare with your version of node. Couldn't find an eslintrc validator, but you could try experimenting with your file. Remove all the rules except one and see if you can get that one to work. The eqeqeq rule is an easy one to test and the syntax has changed over eslint versions so you might be able to make headway that way.